# How do I check if the user is authenticated with the database using PyMongo?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) for a project, what I have found is that all I need is the server name to create, update or delete any entry/collection or even a database. I mean, it doesn't care if I'm authenticated with a username and password with read/write roles. Here's an example:

```
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
 db = client.wow
 db.wowagain.insert_one({'field':'value'})
```

My question is: 
Is it safe to use Mongodb with python applications, specially with web applications?

I have also tried [mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) for Django and still I found the same.

Comment: where is the auth code? have you enabled authentication at mongodb server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first enable authentication on the server with `--auth` and create an administrator account on the server; after that, authentication is enforced.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: So, on Ubuntu, how am I going to do this with this command `sudo service mongod start` ?

Comment: This seems like a starting point: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/#step-enable-mongodb-authentication